# copy files in parallel by reading what files to copy from few other files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, scp

I am working on a little complicated shell script for the first time and below is what it should do:

- During startup, it figures out what is my `clientid` by looking at `host-mapping.txt` file. If I cannot find `clientid` for my hostname then I need to exit from shell script with non zero status code and log error message.
- Now once I have valid `clientid`, I will extract `primary files` from `primary-mappings.txt` file and `secondary files` from `secondary-mappings.txt` file for that valid `clientid`. If for whatever reason, I cannot find either primary or secondary files for that `clientid` from that file, then I will exit from shell script and log an error message.
- Now once I have valid primary and secondary files for that `clientid` then I will start copying those files in parallel using `gnu-parallel` from `local_server`. All primary files will go to `primary` folder and all secondary files will go to `secondary` folder. If files are not there in `hold1` folder on remote servers then it should be there on `hold2` folder.
- Now once all the files are copied, I will verify at the end to make sure all the primary and secondary files are present for that `clientid` in those two folders but if for whatever reason, I cannot find those files then I want to exit from the shell script with message that tells me what files are missing.

Below is my script and it does the job but I would like to see if there is any better or efficient way to do above things since this is my first time writing little complicated script so wanted to check this out. As of now, I don't have mechanism to exit out of shell script if I cannot find `primary` or `secondary` files for that `clientid` and also I don't have mechanism to exit out of shell script if during the verification phase some files are missing.

```
#!/bin/bash
path=/home/goldy/scripts
mapfiles=(primary-mappings.txt secondary-mappings.txt)
hostfile=host-mapping.txt
machines=(machine1769.abc.host.com proctek5461.def.host.com letyrs87541.pqr.host.com)
# folders on local box where to copy files
primary=/data01/primary
secondary=/data02/secondary
# folders on remote servers from where to copy files
export hold1=/data/snapshot/$1
export hold2=/data/snapshot/$2

date1=$(date +"%s")
# this will tell me what's my clientid given my current hostname
getProperty () {
   prop_value=$(hostname -f)
   prop_key=`cat $path/$hostfile | grep "$prop_value" | cut -d'=' -f1`
   echo $(echo $prop_key | tr -dc '0-9')
}
# if I can't find clientid for my hostname, then I will log a message 
# and exit out of shell script with non zero status code
clientid=$(getProperty)
[ -z "$clientid" ] && { echo "cannot find clientid for $(hostname -f)"; exit 1; }

# now once I have valid clientid, then I will get primary and secondary mapping
# from the "host-mapping.txt" file
declare -a arr
mappingsByClientID () {
  id=$1 # 1 to 5
  file=$path/${mapfiles[$2]} # 0 to 1
  arr=($(sed -r "s/.*\b${id}=\[([^]\]+).*/\1/; s/,/ /g" $file))
  echo "${arr[@]}"
}

# assign output of function to an array
pri=($(mappingsByClientID $clientid 0))
snd=($(mappingsByClientID $clientid 1))

echo "primary files: ${pri[@]}"
echo "secondary files: ${snd[@]}"

# figure out which machine you want to use to start copying files from
case $(hostname -f) in
    *abc.host.com)
        local_server=("${machines[0]}")
        ;;
    *def.host.com)
        local_server=("${machines[1]}")
        ;;
    *pqr.host.com)
        local_server=("${machines[2]}")
        ;;
    *) echo "unknown host: $(hostname -f), exiting." && exit 1 ;;
    # ?
esac
export local="$local_server"

# deleting files before we start copying
find "$primary" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm -fv {} \;
find "$secondary" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm -fv {} \;

do_copy() {
  el=$1
  primsec=$2
  (scp -C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no goldy@"$local":"$hold1"/hello_monthly_"$el"_999_1.data "$primsec"/. > /dev/null 2>&1) || (scp -C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no goldy@"$local":"$hold2"/hello_monthly_"$el"_999_1.data "$primsec"/. > /dev/null 2>&1)
}
export -f do_copy
# copy files in parallel
parallel -j "$3" do_copy {} $primary ::: ${pri[@]} &
parallel -j "$3" do_copy {} $secondary ::: ${snd[@]} &
wait
echo "all files copied"

# this is for verification to see all files got copied or not
# in primary and secondary folder
set -- "$primary" "$secondary"
typeset -n array
for array in pri snd; do
    for num in "${array[@]}"; do
        name="hello_monthly_${num}_999_1.data"
        if [ ! -f "$1/$name" ]; then
            { echo "$name" not found in "$1" >&2 && exit 1; }
        fi
    done
    shift
done

date2=$(date +"%s")
diff=$(($date2-$date1))
echo "Total Time Taken - $(($diff / 3600)) hours and $(((diff/60) % 60)) minutes and $(($diff % 60)) seconds elapsed."
```

Below is my `host-mapping.txt` file and it will have lot more entries. Here value is a valid hostname and key will be string "k" followd by some number and that number should be there in mapping files.

```
k1=machineA.abc.com
k2=machineB.abc.com
k3=machineC.def.com
k4=machineD.pqr.com
k5=machineO.abc.com
```

And below is my sample mapping files:

**primary_mappings.txt**

```
{1=[343, 0, 686, 1372, 882, 196], 2=[687, 1, 1373, 883, 197, 736, 1030, 1569], 3=[1374, 2, 884, 737, 198, 1570], 4=[1375, 1032, 1424, 3, 885, 1228], 5=[1033, 1425, 4, 200, 886]}
```

**secondary_mappings.txt**

```
{1=[1152, 816, 1488, 336, 1008], 2=[1153, 0, 817, 337, 1489, 1009, 1297], 3=[1, 1154, 1490, 338], 4=[1155, 2, 339, 1491, 819, 1299, 1635], 5=[820, 1492, 340, 3, 1156]}
```

For example: `clientid` 1 has `343, 0, 686, 1372, 882, 196` primary files and `1152, 816, 1488, 336, 1008` secondary files. Similarly for other `clientids` as well.

Comment: The question is well written. However, since the problem and program are quite long to read and fully understand, you are asking for a lot of effort. You could start by pinpointing a single operation that you feel you are not doing efficiently, and ask if there are better ways to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I have a few suggestions so I thought I'd write an answer.

1. There is an inconsistency regarding `primary_mappings.txt` and
   `secondary_mappings.txt`, which are called `primary-mappings.txt`
   and `secondary-mappings.txt` in the script. You should of course
   rename the files (or change their name the script).
2. I'd create two functions to handle logging to STDERR and exiting the program. This has the advantage of better readability, is less error prone, and allows you to exit from within function calls (it answers *I don't have mechanism to exit out of shell script*):

   ```
   trap "exit 1" TERM
   export TOP_PID=$$
   log_error () {
      echo "$1">&2;
   }
   log_error_and_exit () {
      echo "$1">&2;
      kill -s TERM $TOP_PID
   }
   ```
3. You seem to be wanting to log errors to STDERR, but sometimes you write to STDOUT. Assuming you simply forgot a couple of `>&2`, it is easy to standardize that by using our newly created functions:

   **a.**

   ```
   [ -z "$clientid" ] && { echo "cannot find clientid for $(hostname -f)"; exit 1; }
   ```

   becomes:

   ```
   [ -z "$clientid" ] && { log_error_and_exit "Cannot find ClientID for $(hostname -f)"; }
   ```

   **b.**

   ```
   *) echo "unknown host: $(hostname -f), exiting." && exit 1 ;;
   ```

   becomes:

   ```
   *) log_error_and_exit "Unknown host: $(hostname -f), exiting." ;;
   ```
4. You seem to have forgotten to do this:

   > If for whatever reason, I cannot find either primary or secondary
   >   files for that clientid from that file, then I will exit from shell
   >   script and log an error message.

   ```
   mappingsByClientID () {
     id=$1 # 1 to 5
     file=$path/${mapfiles[$2]} # 0 to 1
     if [[ $(< $file) != *" $1="* ]]; then
         log_error_and_exit "ClientID $1 out of range for $file";
     fi
     arr=($(sed -r "s/.*\b${id}=\[([^]\]+).*/\1/; s/,/ /g" $file))
     echo "${arr[@]}"
   }
   ```
5. You currently don't do this:

   > if for whatever reason, I cannot find those files then I want to exit
   >   from the shell script with message that tells me what files are
   >   missing.

   Since you `exit` as soon a a file is found missing, you'll never get more than one file reported! The solution is to create a variable to keep track of an error status, and check for it at the end of the verification:

   ```
   # this is for verification to see all files got copied or not
   # in primary and secondary folder
   set -- "$primary" "$secondary"
   typeset -n array
   errors=false
   for array in pri snd; do
       for num in "${array[@]}"; do
           name="hello_monthly_${num}_999_1.data"
           if [ ! -f "$1/$name" ]; then
               {  log_error "$name not found in $1" && errors=true; }
           fi
       done
       shift
   done
   if [ "$errors" = true ]; then
       exit 1
   fi
   ```